# Performance of a KVM over IP device?

Tags: networking, video, bandwidth, kvm-switch, 3d-graphics

I'm recently looking for a KVM-over-IP device for a single computer connection. I'm especially looking for a device that is capable of transmitting high quality output from a VGA or DVI (the output will be mostly from 3D applications and videos), keyboard/mouse input and sound output. I presume that the overall performance of the KVM device relies heavily on the network bandwidth. I found several products that seem to transmit all those 4 components, but I cannot really imagine the speed/responsiveness of such connection.

So my question is: Are generally KVM-over-IP devices capable of such transmissions (3D games) in real time? (assuming the 10/100Mbps connection or higher).

I heard that some VNC clients (such as RealVNC) are usually used to control the KVM device - so are even these client applications designed to handle such requests in real time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at iKVM, it seems to be nothing more than a glorified headless tower.
Nonetheless, unless you have a super-expensive Internet connection (upwards of 50MBps) gaming is going to be moderately to extremely unbearable. Whereas technologies like RDP or XDMCP send draw instructions to the remote computer, VNC (and I presume iKVM, but I'm not 100% sure) would do little more than stream a screencast of your computer and then fake the mouse and keyboard.
If you're remotely controlling a computer to edit video and play video games on it, unless your town is chosen for Google fiber (or, in the case of Ethernet, you run a superconducter lab), the experience won't be, to understate, dull.

Comment: Well, this is not supposed to be accessed through internet, but only through LAN, so as I said there's gonna be always at least 100 Mbps full duplex connection.

Comment: But then you may as well use cable extenders and a KVM switch. The signal would be uncompressed and a whole lost faster that way.